# Euler to Trigonometric - Particular solution

Tags: trigonometry

I am back to studying after some years out and I simply forgot the steps that allowed this to function. I recall this is basic, but I can't seem to crack the thing. This is a particular kind of 2nd degree differential equation - one in which the damping is neglected and thus the structure should vibrate endlessly.

The textbook has:
$$
A_1e^{i\lambda t}+A_2e^{-i\lambda t}
$$

Which yields by using Euler's formula the following form:

$$
A_1\sin(\gamma t)+A_2\sin(\gamma t)
$$

I am aware of Euler's formula. **What I can't do is making the first equation resemble the exponential => sine equation to consume the exponential and turn them into pure sines.**

It is shameful, I know, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have confused $\gamma$ and $\lambda$ and must have a typo (please check closely).  But assuming you fix that:  Use Euler's equation, $e^{i \lambda t} = \cos (\lambda t) + i \sin (\lambda t)$ and substitute, knowing that $\cos (x) = \cos (-x)$ and $\sin (x) = -\sin (-x)$.

Comment: I actually though that the change of name in the book was simply related to gathering together some constants...

Answer (score 0):

(I think there are typos in your original post regarding $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ and you also have two $\sin$ functions. )

\begin{equation}
A_1 e^{i\lambda t} + A_2 e^{-i\lambda t} = A_1 ( \cos( \lambda t) + i \sin(\lambda t)) + A_2 ( \cos( \lambda t) - i \sin(\lambda t))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=(A_1 +A_2) \cos(\lambda t) + i (A_1 - A_2) \sin(\lambda t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= B_1 \cos(\lambda t) + B_2 \sin(\lambda t)
\end{equation}

Comment: Hello! I thank you for your time in answering me :) The thing I missed is how the imaginary unit disappears from the sine member between the second and third line. Or did you just say that $B_2=i.(A_1-A_2)$?

Comment: @Scudelari Yes exactly that. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But why it doesn't matter that the sine is imaginary?

Comment: @Scudelari The actual numerical values of the coefficients would be determined by boundary conditions so $B_2$ needn't be complex.